# Passing values to a PowerShell script in a TeamCity metarunner

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I've got a metarunner defined like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meta-runner name="Fancy Pancy">
  [...]
  <build-runners>
    <runner name="Fancy Pancy" type="jetbrains_powershell">
      <parameters>
        [...]
<param name="jetbrains_powershell_scriptArguments"><![CDATA-Optional:%SomeOptMetarunnerParam%
-Required:%SomeReqMetarunnerParam%]]></param>

<param name="jetbrains_powershell_script_code"><![CDATA[#Requires -Version 7
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [string] $Optional,
  [string] $Required
)
        [...]
```

My problem is the following: if the user keeps the optional parameter empty, the PowerShell execution thinks that "-Required:%SomeReqMetarunnerParam" is the argument value for the "Optional" parameter and finally fails because a value for the "Required" parameter is missing. If the user does give a value for the optional parameter, everything works as intended.

I've worked around it by redefining the parameters as follows (note the quotes):

```
<param name="jetbrains_powershell_scriptArguments"><![CDATA-Optional:'%SomeOptMetarunnerParam%'
-Required:'%SomeReqMetarunnerParam%']]></param>
```

This works, however, the quotes become part of the value. So I have to trim them at the beginning of the PowerShell script which is clearly bad style and not clean code at all.

Is there a trick on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to overcome my problem. I removed the scriptArguments XML, the CmdletBinding and the param declaration completely. Instead I simply access the variables at the beginning of the jetbrains_powershell_script_code XML:

```
$Optional = "%Optional%"
$Required = "%Required%"
```

The required check is done by TeamCity's `validationMode` property further up the XML.